# How can I create a second website with host header binding?

Tags: iis, web, hostheaders

I have a website working fine on IIS manager. I created a new site with it sharing the same IP and port. For the host header I put in the domain to the site. When i currently go to the domain i get a 
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

I checked to make sure anonymous is enabled and setup but still no luck. it doesn't ask for credentials when accessing the site.

At this point i'm not sure what else to do. Does anyone have ideas that I could try?

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time in my domain service site. I apparently put in the wrong IP address to the website server and instead was pointing towards my exchange server.